# How can I replace same value on second row?

Tags: pandas

Is this possible to do in DataFrame Pandas? I want to keep only first row value on the same column, replace second row, and on with 0

Input

```
Name--------Date-------Amount-----Labor  
A--------------1/1/1972-------5-------- 0.3  
A--------------1/1/1972-------5-------- 0.1  
A--------------1/1/1972-------5-------- 0.7  
A--------------1/1/1972-------1-------- 0.3     
B--------------7/2/1980-------1-------- 0.6  
B--------------7/2/1980-------1-------- 0.3  
B--------------7/2/1980-------1-------- 0.7  
C--------------6/9/1965-------4-------- 0.2    
C--------------6/9/1965-------4-------- 0.3  
C--------------6/9/1965-------4-------- 0.4
```

Output

```
Name--------Date-------Amount-----Labor  
A--------------1/1/1972-------5-------- 0.3  
A--------------1/1/1972-------0-------- 0.1  
A--------------1/1/1972-------0-------- 0.7  
A--------------1/1/1972-------0-------- 0.3     
B--------------7/2/1980-------1-------- 0.6  
B--------------7/2/1980-------0-------- 0.3  
B--------------7/2/1980-------0-------- 0.7  
C--------------6/9/1965-------4-------- 0.2    
C--------------6/9/1965-------0-------- 0.3  
C--------------6/9/1965-------0-------- 0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `duplicated` with `np.where`:

```
df.Amount = np.where(df.Amount.duplicated(),0, df.Amount)
```

OR with `mask`:

```
df.Amount = df.Amount.mask(pd.Series.duplicated, 0)
```

via `where`:

```
m = df.Amount.duplicated()
df.Amount = df.Amount.where(~m,0)
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Name      Date  Amount  Labor  
0    A  1/1/1972       5      0.3
1    A  1/1/1972       0      0.1
2    A  1/1/1972       0      0.7
3    A  1/1/1972       1      0.3
4    B  7/2/1980       0      0.6
5    B  7/2/1980       0      0.3
6    B  7/2/1980       0      0.7
7    C  6/9/1965       4      0.2
8    C  6/9/1965       0      0.3
9    C  6/9/1965       0      0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I could use a for-loop to look at individual values, to decide if there is a need to change it to '0' or not.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
['A', '1/1/1972', '5', '0.3'],
['A', '1/1/1972', '5', '0.1'],
['A', '1/1/1972', '5', '0.7'],
['A', '1/1/1972', '1', '0.3'],
['B', '7/2/1980', '1', '0.6'],
['B', '7/2/1980', '1', '0.3'],
['B', '7/2/1980', '1', '0.7'],
['C', '6/9/1965', '4', '0.2'],
['C', '6/9/1965', '4', '0.3'],
['C', '6/9/1965', '4', '0.4']], columns = ['Name', 'Date', 'Amount', 'Labor'])

df['Amount_new'] = df['Amount'][0]
for i in range(1, df.shape[0]):
    if df.loc[i, 'Amount'] == df.loc[i-1, 'Amount']:
        df.loc[i, 'Amount_new'] = 0
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'Amount_new'] = df.loc[i, 'Amount']
```

Output df is:

```
  Name  Date    Amount  Labor   Amount_new
0   A   1/1/1972    5   0.3     5
1   A   1/1/1972    5   0.1     0
2   A   1/1/1972    5   0.7     0
3   A   1/1/1972    1   0.3     1
4   B   7/2/1980    1   0.6     0
5   B   7/2/1980    1   0.3     0
6   B   7/2/1980    1   0.7     0
7   C   6/9/1965    4   0.2     4
8   C   6/9/1965    4   0.3     0
9   C   6/9/1965    4   0.4     0
```